# How to understand string concatenation (||) and bit-wise exclusive-or ( (+) ) in cryptography

Tags: cryptography, concatenation, bitwise-xor

Here's a question to prove that `F` is a block cipher.

```
Algorithm F_{K1||K2} (x1||x2)
return AES^(-1) (K1,x1(+)x2) || AES(K2,X2(+)K1)
```

I want to prove the inverse of `F`, but I don't understand these two operation `||` and `(+)`, so I don't know how to simplify it.

```
Algorithm F^{-1}_{K1||K2} (AES^(-1) (K1,x1(+)x2)|| AES(K2,X2(+)K1))
return (x1||x2)
```

`AES^(-1) (K1,x1(+)x2)` as `x1`
`AES(K2,X2(+)K1)` as `x2`

Could you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations in cryptography are usually defined over bits and not bytes, but they mean the same thing over bytes or collection of bytes.

Concatenation examples:

```
1 || 1 = 11
11100 || 10101000 = 1110010101000
```

XOR returns 0 if both operands are equal. Otherwise 1:

```
  100100101
+ 001100110
-----------
  101000011
```